# html5 accessibility for screen readers

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

How can I add accessibility to this

**Text:**

Buttons and Images and anchors:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button class="btn btn-default">
        <img class="profile-img">
        <span id="user-name">john</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">
         Log out
         <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<div>
    <a  href="" class="change-user-link">Change recipient</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a specific question? Surely you don't expect someone to do your work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you are suited to properly add semantics to your code and content, so we really can't do this for you. But, here are some important things to remember/do/follow:

- Your HTML is not event valid, so start by [correcting that](http://validator.w3.org).
- Don't ever use an HTML element because of the way it makes the
  visible page look (i.e. using a heading like `<h4>` to make text
  small and bold). CSS should be used for all layout and presentation.
- Use the most appropriate HTML elements to convey the **semantics** of the content you have. For
  example, go ahead and use the `<table>` element if you actually are
  trying to display tabular data and use `<ul>` and `<li>` to make menus.
- Despite the (many) myths, the HTML5 sectioning elements (`section`,
  `article`, `nav`, `aside`) are not recognized by most screen readers. Their use actually makes creating a valid document outline much more difficult.
- The proper use of heading (`<h1>`...`<h6>`) elements is the best
  thing you can do to [convey a proper document structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines).
- Use [WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles) landmark roles where applicable as that has been a
  standard for many years and all the major screen readers understand
  it.

Answer (score 1):

Too little information provided. Context needed. That being said:

- Add an `alt` attribute to the `<img>`,
- make sure the link has a valid `href`,
- don't rely on FontAwesome icons to convey critical information,
- maybe dump the `role` attribute as it may not be needed (context necessary to know if needed).

Answer (score 0):

For images, provide the `alt` attribute to the `<img>` tag, which is a description of the image. For example, `<img class="profile-img" alt="profile picture">`.

For semantics, use `<em>` instead of `<i>` and `<strong>` instead of `<b>`.

Also, look into [ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/) (Accessible Rich Internet Applications). A useful ARIA attribute is the role attribute. It provides extra content about the element's purpose and functionality.

Comment: isn't it enough to use the`for` attribute for labels and then use the map it to the `id` of the input element. Where is it possible to use the aria elements in any of my html elements

Comment: FYI Not using `alt` with images makes the HTML invalid, so it's a good suggestion, but part of the validation process. Also, `i` has a very particular and valid meanings in HTML5. `i` is for alternate voice. while `em` is for general emphasis.

Comment: @dream123 ARIA roles can be used all throughout your document and, yes, `label` elements are for `form` elements and they can map to them with the `for` attribute that matches a form element's `id` or the form element can be wrapped by a `label`.

Comment: One note of caution: ARIA should not be used unless absolutely necessary. While ARIA can add semantics to non-semantic elements, it does not add the necessary keyboard and other interactions, requiring the developer to do that instead. See [Rules of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#notes2)